# How to find out the dimensions of a 3-D model constructed using an object file and the patch function onto the figure window?

Tags: image, image-processing, 3d, matlab-figure, dimensional-modeling

I have attached the object file from which we are trying to find the dimensions(please open the objectfile.txt in notepad++ or sublime text as it groups the values into to rows and columns respectively). Using this object file we have plotted the image onto the figure window using Patch function. Now, what we want to achieve is to find the dimensions of the 3-D object model. We aren't able to find any useful links. The main purpose is to find the waist size and the shoulder length of the 3D model. Here's an image of the figure window.

How should we approach this problem? Is there any algorithm that we have to follow?[Image of 3D model on figure window in matlab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5W2ew.png)

Comment: what language is this - please specify in tags

Comment: I have used MATLAB itself. Trying to find a solution to get the dimensions of the 3D model constructed on the image window.